# How to use Entity Framework in PCL

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, portable-class-library

My question is really very simple, I want to know the steps to generate EF model in my PCL to using a sqlce db.
I have installed EF nuget package but now I don't know how to continue. I search google also, but nothing found.

Comment: I think a "I want to know the steps" isn't a good beginning, StackOverflow questions shouldn't be little bit more _specific_ and   they don't replace a **good** Google search. Anyway you can't, with latest VS updates a PCL will also target Windows Phone (I'm assuming - you don't say - that your target is 4.5 and Windows 8.x because for previous versions it worked) and you can't use EF there (so far).

Comment: What specifically did you search for on Google? I do get useful results, in particular I get an official answer from an EF developer that says with the current version of EF, you just plain can't.

Comment: I am not a good developer just a beginner, so I am thinking that if EF is available for PCL than there should be a way to use like traditional way.

Answer (score 2):

EF does not work in PCL, as it depends on the full .NET desktop Framework

The next/new version of EF (EF7) will be PCL based.

But SQL CE only runs on platform that support the full .NET desktop framework anyway